# How to compare contents of two arrays? how can we point the specific lines on one of the array if conditions meet?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have `${array1[@]}`

```
Application_1007896 60
Application_8907897 50
Application_5678342 7
Application_1289764 9
Application_8907899 5
Application_8917899 21
```

and `${array2[@]}`

```
Application_5678342
Application_1289764
Application_8907897
Application_5678342
Application_1289764
```

How can we check if the content of `${array2[@]}` resides in `${array1[@]}`. when the condition meets then should be able to fetch the corresponding values (in which the conditions meet) from `${array1[@]}` and sum up them.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: I would create an associative array from the elements of array1. Then it is very straightforward to loop up the numeric values based on the elements of array2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code block below assumes second array has value and assumes that it will only return entries that exist in both arrays.

```
for entry_1 in "${array1[@]}" ; do
   for entry_2 in "${array2[@]}" ; do
       entry_1_split=(${entry_1// /})
       entry_2_split=(${entry_2// /})
       if [[ "${entry_1_split[0]}" == "${entry_2_split[1]}" ]] ; then
          echo "${entry_1_split[0}} $((${entry_1_split[1]}+${entry_2_split[1]))"
       fi
   done
done
```